# how to move last div down when sub menu comes up

Tags: html, css, responsive

I modified the code below from W3 to make it responsive.  Any suggestions to make it better appreciated.

Here's the main problem:  How do I make the last div (with class "move-down") move down the page when the red sub menu comes up?

```css
p:empty{
   display:none;
   margin:0;
}

.entry-content p{
  margin:0;
}

.subnavbtn button{
  border:0!important;
  box-sizing:unset!important;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
}

/* The navigation menu */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333; 
  line-height:1;  
}

.navbar p{
  line-height:1;  
 }


/* Navigation links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2vw 1.5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:visited{
  color:white;  
}

/* The subnavigation menu */
.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;  
}

.subnav{
  font-size:3vw;
}

/* Subnav button */
.subnav .subnavbtn {
 
  border: none;
  box-sizing:unset!important;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding:  2vw 1.5vw;
  background-color: inherit;
  font:inherit;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;  
  margin: 0;
}

/* Add a red background color to navigation links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */
.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.5%;
  background-color: red;
  width:  95%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the subnav links */
.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Add a grey background color on hover */
.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}

/* When you move the mouse over the subnav container, open the subnav content */
.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}

.move-down{
   width:100%;
   height:200px;
   background-color:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">   
   <!-- The navigation menu -->
   <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <div class="subnav">
         <button class="subnavbtn">About</button>
         <div class="subnav-content">
            <a href="#company">Company</a>
            <a href="#team">Team</a>
            <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="subnav">
         <button class="subnavbtn">Services</button>
         <div class="subnav-content">
            <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
            <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
            <a href="#package">Package</a>
            <a href="#express">Express</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="subnav">
         <button class="subnavbtn">Partners</button>
         <div class="subnav-content">
            <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="move-down"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this applies to your problem, but I'll ask anyway: Have you tried display flex and changing the order attribute of your elements depending on which class is given to them? It removes the need to change properties directly (ex margin, height, position that might interfere with the rest of your page)

Comment: that's an interesting approach but would seem to require an entire rewrite, so no, I haven't considered it

Comment: @DCR, Can you gave pictorial ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the purple div is outside the nav container so you can't manipulate it using `grid` or `flexbox` also you can't move it down when the nav is hovered since there is no selector to do the job however you can use a little javascript to achieve the desired result :

```js
const navbar = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0]
const subnavs = document.getElementsByClassName('subnav')
const purpleDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('move-down')[0]
const subnavHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('subnav')[1].getBoundingClientRect().height

for ( let i =0 ; i <subnavs.length ; i++ ) {
subnavs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  purpleDiv.style.marginTop = subnavHeight + 'px'
  
})
subnavs[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  purpleDiv.style.marginTop = 0 + 'px'
})
}
```

```css
p:empty {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.entry-content p {
  margin: 0;
}

.subnavbtn button {
  border: 0!important;
  box-sizing: unset!important;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
}


/* The navigation menu */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  line-height: 1;
}

.navbar p {
  line-height: 1;
}


/* Navigation links */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2vw 1.5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:visited {
  color: white;
}


/* The subnavigation menu */

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subnav {
  font-size: 3vw;
}


/* Subnav button */

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  border: none;
  box-sizing: unset!important;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 2vw 1.5vw;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Add a red background color to navigation links on hover */

.navbar a:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.5%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the subnav links */

.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Add a grey background color on hover */

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}


/* When you move the mouse over the subnav container, open the subnav content */

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}

.move-down {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <!-- The navigation menu -->
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">About</button>
      <div class="subnav-content">
        <a href="#company">Company</a>
        <a href="#team">Team</a>
        <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Services</button>
      <div class="subnav-content">
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Partners</button>
      <div class="subnav-content">
        <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="move-down"></div>
```

Comment: This is really good.  Thanks.  I tried this in full page mode and it doesn't quite move the div down far enough.  Is that a stackoverflow issue?

Comment: @DCR That's because it runs the first time when the editor is small then you enlarge it, if you'd right click and reload the frame you'll see that it works, the code snippet provided in this answer doesn't care for responsiveness,  which you need to implement

Comment: I'd recommend using `getBoundingClientRect()` function to get the exact height of the element instead of `offsetHeight` which rounds value down and leaves visible gaps on small screens